# Using hex values for colors in LaTex/MathJax

Tags: javascript, html, latex, mathjax

I have a couple variables in my javascript that hold color values, i.e.

```
var color = #ABCDEF
```

I'm trying to use these variables to color some text that I have, but it seems that MathJax doesn't support hex color values. Is there anyway to circumvent this in order to use the variable in the \color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `\color[HTML]{ABCDEF}`.

You need to add `\usepackage{xcolor}` to the preamble.

Answer (score 3):

> it seems that MathJax doesn't support hex color values

Sure it does.  E.g., `\color{#ABCDEF}{x+1}` works fine in the standard configurations.  You can also load MathJax's color extension to make the `\color` command more compatible with LaTeX's syntax (thought it doesn't implement the HTML color model suggested by sergej, but does do rgb and several others).

You don't give enough of your code to tell how you intend to use you color variable, but one thing that is wrong is that you have left out the quotation marks:

```
var color = "#ABCDEF";
```

The issue now will be how you get this value into the `\color` command within you math expressions.  If you are trying to make *all* the math on your page be a different color, it would be best to use CSS for that.  E.g.,

```
<style>
  .MathJax {color: #ABCDEF}
</style>
```

would do it for MathJax's HTML-CSS output.

Comment: Well, here's a sample of my test code: https://jsfiddle.net/gamea12/u09or8aL/

What I'm trying to do right now is to color only the text within the brackets, and not the following code. If you could also give a reason as to why it's shifted so much to the right, I would also be thankful for that, please.